# How do I set up my htaccess file to enable history mode in VueJS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js

I want to enable history mode in my VueJS app so my url's do not contain `#`. e.g. `https://www.mybusiness.com/#/articles`

When I enable history mode it removes the `#` but I cannot visit url's directly such as `https://www.mybusiness.com/articles` as it return a 404 error.

Research tells me I need to edit my .htaccess file to include something like: (as suggested by VueJS docs)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, if I add this to my .htaccess file although I can visit my url's directly - if I try to log in to my app I get '**JavaScript is not enabled'**.

How do I set up my .htaccess file properly to allow history mode in VueJS and still have JavaScript enabled?

***my .htaccess file:***

```
RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
  # RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

 </IfModule>
```

With the code above **I do not get the javascript is not enabled error** but **I do get a 404 error on trying to access a direct url**.

If I uncomment that second last line `RewriteRule . /index.html [L]` then I get a couple of errors both saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and my app fails to load.

I have my app in the public_html folder of my shared hosting account. I have just copied the contents of my built dist folder into this public_html folder.

I'm unsure if my error is something to do with that commented out last line not locating the html properly, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a conflict between the rewrite rule for index.html which served my front end, and index.php which served my backend api's.

To fix it I inserted this line before the RewriteRule for index.php.  This overcome the conflict and worked as it should.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/`